# Within "Unanswered" tab, with a favourite tag selected, "all" questions are highlighted

Tags: bug, status-completed, unanswered-questions, tag-highlighting

When in the "Unanswered" tab, and with a "favourite tag" selected, *all* questions are highlighted to signify they include my favourite tag.

Surely this is incorrect behaviour, as when I have a favourite tag selected then all questions *will* include my favourite tag?

Within the "Unanswered" tab, this happens in all sub tabs:
my tags; newest; votes; no answers;

I would have thought this area should behave just like any of the other tabs:

- Without a favourite tag selected, questions with my favourite tag(s)
  will be highlighted
- With a favourite tag selected there won't be any highlighting

---

### Notes

The same happens when multiple favourite tags are selected.

This only happens in the main "Unanswered" tab (e.g., does not happen in "Questions" tab with sub-tab "Unanswered" selected).

I have reproduced/tested on 3 sites, all have the same highlighting logic (Unanswered tab + fave tag = all highlighted):
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/php
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php
https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/feature-request

To reproduce in the above links you'll need favourite tags: PHP; PHP; Feature-Request; (respectively)

---

FWIW (don't think it'll matter) am using:
Iceweasel 31.2.0
Debian jessie/sid

Comment: looking into that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in build `2014.11.18.2756` on meta and `2014.11.18.2021` on sites.

Comment: Nice! Highlighting works as with other site tabs. Although, I can only select one favourite tag at a time. I'm sure I could select multiple favourite tags before. I can still select more than one non-favourite tag at a time - or one fave and multiple non-fave. (not that I'm so bothered, just letting you know in case it's a side effect of any changes)

Comment: @James the same favorite tag click behavior is there on the home and question pages, which weren't altered by this changeset. You can't select more than one at a time from the favorite tags section. You can however select additional tags from the related tags section once you've clicked a favorite tag. So that's where the confusion possibly originates. If you're really annoyed with it, a [tag:feature-request] might be appropriate.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought I'd selected multiple favourite tags when testing this, to be honest. No worries, cheers.

Comment: FYI: [it may not be ideal to treat Unanswered the same as the normal question views when multiple tags are in play](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277219/unanswered-questions-no-longer-adhering-to-favorite-tags#comment119116_277220)